# "What have you done since you got up this morning?" or "What have you been doing since you got up this morning?"

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Why I have to use here Present Perfect or Present Perfect Continous? Do both mean the same?

> What have you done since you got up this morning?
> What have you been doing since you got up this morning?

Comment: My question hast nothing to do with the other question.

Comment: 1. Your question is devoid of context, thus off-topic and would have been closed anyway regardless if it is a duplicate. 2. This question is not deleted. It is closed. 3. If you consider your question not answered by the answer in that post, then edit your question, clarify it, and request it be reopened. Community members will review your request and decide if your question should be reopened. 4. Don't post anything irrelevant in questions. 5. This isn't a discussion forum. Take a [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Why is my question closed?

Comment: Please [edit] your post as advised. Wait for your question to be [reviewed and reopened](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (could take a few days). If your question is not reopened then, you could try posting on [ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/).